# How to use multiprocessing together with multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, cherrypy

CherryPy server uses threads to handle requests. One particular method in my threaded server is very complex and CPU heavy, so I have to use multiprocessing, from inside the method request thread, to parallelize execution.

I thought I'd just replace

```
class Server(object)
    @cherrypy.expose
    def expensive_method(self):
        ...
        x = map(fnc, args)
        ...

def fnc(args):
    # this method doesn't need CherryPy but is expensive to compute
    ...

cherrypy.quickstart(Server())
```

(which works fine) with

```
    def expensive_method(self):
        pool = Pool()
        x = pool.map(fnc, args)
        pool.terminate()
```

but that doesn't work. Even in the simpler case, when I don't use the pool at all,

```
    def expensive_method(self):
        pool = Pool()
        x = map(fnc, args) # <== no pool here! same as the working example
        pool.terminate()
```

I get an exception

```
[08/Jan/2013:20:05:33] ENGINE Caught signal SIGTERM.
2013-01-08 20:05:33,919 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-3) : [08/Jan/2013:20:05:33] ENGINE Caught signal SIGTERM.
[08/Jan/2013:20:05:33] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
2013-01-08 20:05:33,920 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-3) : [08/Jan/2013:20:05:33] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[08/Jan/2013:20:05:38] ENGINE Error in 'stop' listener <bound method Server.stop of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x1090c3c90>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/work/workspace/vew/prj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 197, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Volumes/work/workspace/vew/prj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 223, in stop
    wait_for_free_port(*self.bind_addr)
  File "/Volumes/work/workspace/vew/prj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 410, in wait_for_free_port
    raise IOError("Port %r not free on %r" % (port, host))
IOError: Port 8888 not free on '127.0.0.1'
```

I think this happens at the end of the request, either after or during `pool.terminate()`.

The forked worker processes don't do anything with the server or ports as such. Is there any way to tell CherryPy and/or multiprocessing to ignore the "server bits"? I don't need any ports or sockets there in `fnc`.

I need this to work on OSX + Linux, using Python 2.7.1 and CherryPy 3.2.2.

---

PROGRESS 1:

As per Sylvain's suggestion, I tried `pool = Pool(initializer=cherrypy.server.unsubscribe)`. There are no more exceptions, everything works fine, but in the log I see

```
[08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Caught signal SIGTERM.
2013-01-08 21:16:35,908 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-10) : [08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Caught signal SIGTERM.
[08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
2013-01-08 21:16:35,909 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-10) : [08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
2013-01-08 21:16:35,909 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-10) : [08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus EXITING
2013-01-08 21:16:35,909 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-10) : [08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus EXITED
2013-01-08 21:16:35,910 : INFO : _cplogging:201 : error(CP Server Thread-10) : [08/Jan/2013:21:16:35] ENGINE Bus EXITED
```

Is that alright? Could any trouble come from this (say, when serving multiple requests in different threads concurrently)?

---

PROGRESS 2:

Actually the above leaves idle processes behind occasionally :( So it doesn't work fine. Strange thing is, these idle processes were spawned by `Pool`, so they ought be daemons, but they actually stay alive even after killing the parent.

---

PROGRESS 3:

I moved the forking (=`Pool()` call) outside of the request handling method, but *after* initializing all the necessary state (so that the worker processes can see this state). No more errors or exceptions.

Bottom line: multiprocessing and multithreading don't work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which type of object does 'self' refer to? At which point do you initialize and start your forked process? Perhaps a little more code would help diagnose the issue.

Okay this works just fine:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

import cherrypy

def run_in_sub_proc(size):
    for i in range(size):
        print os.getpid(), i
        time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        pool.map_async(run_in_sub_proc, (3, 5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.engine.subscribe('stop', pool.join)
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you try making fnc an actual module level function rather than a method?

Comment: I would probably not create the pool within the CherryPy page handler. Threads and multiprocess aren't always the best friends as I recently learnt http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: Damn I had not read your initial post properly. If you don't need the server, just do this: `cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()` before the quickstart call.

Comment: Well, the master needs the server (=*is* the server), but the forked workers in the pool don't.

Comment: I tried `pool = Pool(initializer=cherrypy.server.unsubscribe)`, and there are no more exceptions! Still some strange error in log, will update the question, would appreciate your comment.

Comment: There are two things you don't want to start doing before a fork in any program: create threads, and listen on a socket. See http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them for example. Unfortunately, most of CherryPy is about doing both. That's why doing it outside the request, before you start the engine, can work OK but forking inside a request is a recipe for pain.

Comment: I had to position the fork call (`Pool()`) more carefully, because I need some of the server state available in the workers. But otherwise this approach works, so I'm accepting this answer, thanks a lot @SylvainHellegouarch and @fumanchu.